# Can not parse nested dictionary

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I want to parse this JSON data, but I can't make it.

JSON data is like

[image: jsondata]

My code is:

```
session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:{( data , response , error) -> Void in
    if let data = data {
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data , options: .allowFragments) as! Any {
        print(jsonObj)
                if  let postdata = (jsonObj as AnyObject).value(forKey: "postdata") {
                    print(postdata)
                    //if let something = postdata["best_before"] as? NSDictionary{
                       // print(something)
```

Comment: What's the error that you're receiving?

Comment: Keep calm, do it piece by piece (check what sublevel you manage to get or fail to get) and debug. Why "as! Any"? Why using AnyObject and Any? Why using NSDictionary in Swift3 ?

Answer (score 0):

The root object is clearly a dictionary (`[String:Any]`) not just something (`Any`) and use proper error handling and optional bindings to unwrap the optionals safely.

The value for key `postdata` is an array of dictionaries (`[[String:Any]]`). And don't use `valueForKey` – and by the way those silly bridge casts to `AnyObject` – unless you can explain why you explicitly need KVC.

`.allowFragments` is not needed because the root object is a collection type.

```
       do {
          if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any],
             let postdata = jsonObj["postdata"] as? [[String:Any]] {
               for data in postdata {
                 for (key, value) in data {
                     print(key, value)
                 }
              }
          }
       } catch {
         print(error)
       }
```